# How do I make vim use the syntax highlighting of another file location?

Tags: vim, sudo, filetype

I don't ever use `sudo vim /path/to/some.file`; I always use `sudoedit`. However, this means that vim doesn't see the correct path. As an example, when I open `/etc/http/conf/httpd.conf`, sudoedit makes a copy of httpd.conf and then uses vim to open that. So instead of vim seeing that file, it sees `"/var/tmp/httpdXX3H43AK.conf"`(for example). This means that vim's syntax highlighting system doesn't see the proper filetype. If I were to simply open the file without using sudo(and therefore without write access), vim would see the file location and decide that the syntax highlighting filetype needs to be apache. However, since it's not in that location, it doesn't get the apache syntax type and gets a filetype of conf.

I'm looking for some way(a command-line switch?) to tell vim (and more specifically, the syntax highlighting) "this file should be treated as if it were in this other location." I can manually run `:se syntax=apache` and the highlighting is back to what it should be. However, that requires me to know the correct syntax and is one extra step that I don't think I should have to take. Does anyone know some way to use sudoedit and get it to use the correct file location?

Context: CentOS 7.1, vim version: vim-enhanced-7.4.160-1.el7.x86_64

Answer (score 4):

Add `set modeline` to your `vimrc`, then add a line like this to the end of your `httpd.conf`:

```
# vim: filetype=apache
```

Of course, you can also do that with other files.  See `:help auto-setting` for more information.